# link received error when resetting password with fosuserbundle, symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, passwords, fosuserbundle

I am using Symfony2 and Fosuserbundle on my website. But I have a problem when I want to reset my password.

-- When I go to the /resetting/request page I first put my email.
    I receive an email with a link :
 http://xxxx-xxxx.c9users.io/web/app_dev.php/resetting/reset/UmOqQME0hnRgsXQ2RVjJ02TvogHyabs9L_YHiNnkIfA

--When I click at this link I see a form for /resetting/request not /resetting/reset/{token}.

knowing that confirmation link for registration It works well.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any modifications to your app/config/config.yml file?

Sounds like the timer for your token_ttl is on 0 or too small so the token is expired before you have a chance to reset the password.

app/config/config.yml

```
fos_user:
    resetting:
       token_ttl: 0
```